# C# implementation of facebook's new "batches" functionality

Tags: c#, facebook, httpwebrequest, facebook-graph-api, http-post

So I'm trying to use the new "batches" functionality to the graph API, which is described [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/batch/). I'm think the problem is with the way I'm using POST to submit the data, and I'm having difficulty debugging it. It could be a JSON issue, but I don't think so.
Here's the c#

```
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/");
        httpRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(o.ToString());
        httpRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

        Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
        Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        string APIData = reader.ReadToEnd();
        JObject MyApiData = JObject.Parse(APIData);
```

And the variables "o" contains the following JSON:

```
{
  "access_token": "[my real token]",
  "batch": [
    {
      "method": "get",
      "relative_url": "me"
    },
    {
      "method": "get",
      "relative_url": "me/friends"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? It actually outputs the facebook's developer website documentation....so I think that's a clue that it's messed up ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:
               private void PostBatch(string _token)
        {

```
        string p1 = "access_token=" + Server.UrlEncode(_token);
        string p2  = "&batch=" + Server.UrlEncode(" [ { \"method\": \"get\", \"relative_url\": \"me\" }, { \"method\": \"get\", \"relative_url\": \"me/friends\" } ]");

        try
        {

            HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/");
            httpRequest.Method = "POST";
            httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(p1 + p2);
            httpRequest.ContentLength = bytedata.Length;

            Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
            requestStream.Close();

            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

            string APIData = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Response.Write(APIData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Response.Write(ex.Message.ToString() + "<br>"); }
       // JObject MyApiData = JObject.Parse(APIData);


    }
```

Comment: Way to go, Tim! Very nice, thank you very much for your help on this.

Comment: no problem - knew someone at facebook to help me understand what curl -F was... :)